# is it possible to create a sweetjs macro making multiline strings possible in javascript?

Tags: sweet.js

I am really new to sweet.js.

I would love to have multiline strings in javascript just like in EcmaScript 6:

```
var htmlString = `Say hello to 
multi-line
strings!`;
```

Is it possible to formulate a sweetjs macro handling that (and how ??) ?

Furthermore, would it be possible to do String Interpolation/Templating using that macro just like ES6 does ?

Answer (score 3):

There's an example at the bottom of [this issue on the GitHub project](https://github.com/mozilla/sweet.js/issues/178) that uses backticks.